# Streaming video in realtime from Android cameras to running server application

Tags: android, c++, opencv, video-streaming

I need processing with OpenCV incoming from Android cameras video. I have not idea for pass the video stream to the running c++ application (Should i use Node.js?). I draw it because my English is not so good.

[Working Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUXkY.png)

Comment: Look at https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming and examples

Comment: How i can pass the video stream to the running c++ application dynamically?